# Testing event triggered when typing text in a textarea with Vitest and Vue Test Utils

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils, vitest

I am writing tests with Vitest and Vue Test Utils, but I am having a problem with one of the tests where I want to test the invocation of my reflectInput function when text is typed into the input. However, the test is failing.

View:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, computed } from 'vue';

const inputText = ref('');
const reflectedText = ref('');

const outputText = computed(() => reflect(inputText.value));

const reflectInput = () => {
    reflectedText.value = reflect(inputText.value);
};

function reflect(str: string) {
    return str;
}
</script>
```

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="bg-gray-900 rounded-lg overflow-hidden mx-10">
            <div class="p-6">
                <div class="flex mb-6">
                    <textarea
                        id="textInput"
                        class="w-full bg-gray-800 text-font-color placeholder-font-color h-48 resize-none border border-black rounded-lg px-4 py-2"
                        v-model="inputText"
                        @input="reflectInput"
                    ></textarea>
                    <textarea
                        id="textOutput"
                        class="w-full bg-gray-800 text-font-color placeholder-font-color h-48 resize-none border border-black rounded-lg px-4 py-2 ml-4"
                        :value="outputText"
                        readonly
                    ></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

my test:

```js
 it('should call reflectInput when @input event is triggered on textInput', async () => {
        const wrapper = shallowMount(Home);
        const reflectInputSpy = vi.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'reflectInput');

        const textInput = wrapper.find('#textInput');
        await textInput.setValue('Hello');
        await textInput.trigger('input');

        expect(reflectInputSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

I searched the Vitest documentation to see if there could be something wrong with spyOn, but I couldn't find the issue.